# Как добавлять и удалять тэги вокруг выделенного текста?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я хочу обработать строку внутри textarea получить выделенный текст и добавить вокруг него тэг элемента например

```
$('#click_but').click(function(){
  var el = $('.text_area')
  var control = el[0];
  var text = $(control).val();
  if (control.selectionStart != control.selectionEnd) {
    val = text.substring(control.selectionStart, control.selectionEnd);
    console.log([el.val(),val])
  }
  return false;
});
```

> Текст для теста
>
> Это просто текст
>
> [Выделенный текст]Ссылка[/Выделенный текст]
>
> текст есть текст

```
Текст для теста <br>
Это просто текст <br>
<a href="#">Ссылка</a> <br>
текст есть текст <br>
```

Comment: Объясните подробнее какой тег вы хотите добавить. И приложите рабочий пример разметки html (с кнопкой id click_but, поля text_area и так далее) Таким образом, чтобы это был минимальный воспроизводимый вариант. В текущей формулировке вопроса не понятно что конкретно Вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const area = document.querySelector('content')
const link = document.querySelector('.link')
const unlink = document.querySelector('.unlink')

link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  url = prompt('Введите адрес ссылки', 'http:\/\/');
  document.execCommand('createlink', false, url);
})

unlink.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.execCommand('unlink', false);
})
```

```css
#content {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 15px;
  
}

.link, .unlink {
  color: #272727;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">
  <i class='fa fa-link'></i>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="unlink">
  <i class='fa fa-unlink'></i>
</a>
<div id="content" contenteditable>
  Текст
</div>
```

Comment: Я бы  хотел и вставлять и удалять свой собственный код`document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span id="myId">'+val+'</span>');`